# How can we get Odata $expand result with subquery in expanded result

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

Having following model

```
  public class Product {
     public string Barcode { get; set; }
     public double Price { get; set; }
     public Category Category { get; set; }
  }

  public class Category {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string department { get; set; }
  }
```

Now issue is I am not able to use subquery in $expand query option. Here I have given simple example but in real I have to execute some complex query as subquery.

Cuurently I am getting this:

```
"value": [
  {
     "Price": 500,
     "Category": {
        "Name": "Cricket bat"
        "Department": 235
     }
  }
```

]

Expected result:

```
"value": [
  {
     "Price": 500,
     "Category": {
        "Name": "Cricket bat"
        "Department": "Sport" //This result I want to get using subquery.
     }
  }
```

Table stuct of sub query-

```
Department Table
--------------------------------------------
DepCode |Id     |Seq        |ValueData
235     |1      |0          |1
235     |1      |1          |2
235     |2      |0          |Sport
235     |2      |1          |Food
--------------------------------------------


SubQuery:

select d2.ValueData
from department d1
left join department d2 on d2.id=2 
                        and d1.DepCode = d2.DepCode 
                        and d1.Seq = d2.Seq
where d1.DepCode=235 
      and d1.ValueId=1 
      and d1.ValueData=1
```

In DB I'm getting value 1 (d1.ValueData=1) and using above query I need to fetch "Sport".

Odata Query: /odata/Product?$expand=Category&$select=Price

How I can achive this with odata?

Answer (score 0):

In case i understood correctly, you can use nested query option in $expand to do sub query as

`/odata/Product?$expand=Category($select=Department)&$select=Price`

you can get:

```
"value": [
  {
     "Price": 500,
     "Category": {
             "Department": "Sport"
     }
  }
```

Be noted:

1) $expand can nest "$filter, $orderby, $top, $skip, $select, $expand..."

2) In the latest version, $select also can nest "$filter, $orderby, $top, $skip, $select".

Thanks, hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you for response. But in my case subquery is more complex and don't have any keys in reference table. I have added those details in my post. Kindly provide your suggestion how can I get it with Odata.